# .net propertys Grid - How to loop items?

Tags: c#, .net, controls

Simple question which I can't seem to find the answer on the web.

How do you loop properties in the microsoft propertysgrid control.  example code below is the direction I'm heading in....

```
        AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
        OptionsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = appSettings;

        foreach(var x in OptionsPropertyGrid.items???
```

This is the control..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

any ideas?

thanks,
jason

Comment: What do you want to do?
Why not using reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind to a class the items in the class object are changed.

i.e.

AppSettings appSettings = (AppSettings ) OptionsPropertyGrid.SelectedObject;
string newvalue = appSettings.orginalFieldName;

jason

Comment: You should use the comments boxes to reply to answers or other comments, not new questions. And edit your question if you have more information or a clarification.